# Why is $\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n}$ indeterminate?

Tags: summation, infinity, wolfram-alpha

We all know that $\dfrac{f(x)}{f(x)} = 1$ (where $f(x) \neq 0$) and that $\sum_{n=1}^{x} n = \dfrac{x(x+1)}{2}$.

So, given $f(x) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \sum_{n=1}^{x} n$, we show that $\dfrac{f(x)}{f(x)} = \dfrac{\frac{x(x+1)}{2}}{\frac{x(x+1)}{2}} = \dfrac{x(x+1)}{x(x+1)} = 1$ (where $x \not\in \{-1, 0\}$).

From this, it seems logical that $\dfrac{f(\infty)}{f(\infty)}$ would equal $1$. Now, before you bash me for using $\infty$ like a number, I know [$\infty$ *isn't* a number and can't be used as one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260876/what-exactly-is-infinity), but bear with me. However, [WolframAlpha begs to differ](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28n%3D1%2Cinf%2Cn%29%2Fsum%28n%3D1%2Cinf%2Cn%29) and spits out $(indeterminate)$. I assume it's calculating $\dfrac{\frac{\infty(\infty+1)}{2}}{\frac{\infty(\infty+1)}{2}} = \dfrac{\infty(\infty+1)}{\infty(\infty+1)} = \dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$ which [is $(indeterminate)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=infinity%2Finfinity).

All that makes sense, but because $\infty$ isn't a number, you can't calculate $f(\infty)$ and (from what I've been taught) instead must calculate $\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{f(x)}$, which works out as long as $x \not\in \{-1, 0\}$:

> $\dfrac{f(1)}{f(1)} = \dfrac{1}{1} = 1$
>
> $\dfrac{f(2)}{f(2)} = \dfrac{3}{3} = 1$
>
> ${}\qquad\vdots$
>
> $\dfrac{f(10^{10})}{f(10^{10})} = \dfrac{50\space000\space000\space005\space000\space000\space000}{50\space000\space000\space005\space000\space000\space000} = 1$

And, of course, it works out to be $1$ as long as $x \not\in \{-1, 0\}$. In addition, [when graphed](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3D%28%28n%28n%2B1%29%29%2F2%29%2F%28%28n%28n%2B1%29%29%2F2%29) as $\dfrac{\frac{x(x+1)}{2}}{\frac{x(x+1)}{2}}$ ([WolframAlpha doesn't like the sum form](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3Dsum%28n%3D1%2Cx%2Cn%29%2Fsum%28n%3D1%2Cx%2Cn%29)), you get none other than a $y = 1$ plot (with holes at $x \in \{-1, 0\}$):

[image: plot]

What gives? Is [WolframAlpha wrong again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352505/the-last-few-digits-of-00-are-ldots0000000001-according-to-wolframalpha), or have I just been taught incorrectly ***again*** (like how $\sqrt{x^2} = x$)?

---

If I wanted to use the [analytically continued Riemann-Zeta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-dots-frac112), I could use $\zeta(-1)$ instead of $f(\infty)$, I get $\dfrac{\zeta(-1)}{\zeta(-1)} = \dfrac{-\frac{1}{12}}{-\frac{1}{12}} = 1$. But this is out of the scope of the question.

Comment: This is conceptually similar to this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80262/why-is-int-infty-infty-fracxx21-dx-not-zero

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^xn}{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^xn}=1.$$

However, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty n$ is defined to be $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^x n$, which does not exist, hence

$$\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty n}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty n} =\frac{\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^x n}{\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^x n}$$

is a ratio of two things that do not exist. So, of course, the ratio does not exist.

There are strict rules that tell us when it is okay to pull $\lim$s out of expressions, or to consolidate multiple $\lim$s together, and you have been ignoring these rules.

Answer (score 1):

$+\infty$ is a number, can be used as a number (although the extended real numbers don't satisfy all of the algebraic identities that the real numbers do), and $(+\infty)/(+\infty)$ is undefined (in the same way that $0/0$ is undefined).

And $\sum_{n=1}^{\inf} n = +\infty$.

The expression $\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\inf} n}{\sum_{n=1}^{\inf} n}$ is not indeterminate: it is *undefined*.

Answer (score 0):

The numerator and denominator are $\infty$, so you're asking wolfram alpha "What is $\infty/\infty?$" which doesn't have an answer.  If instead you asked the different question:  What is $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sum_0^Nn / \sum_0^Nn$?  you would get 1.