# Evaluating an improper integral with limits $_{-\infty}^\infty$

Tags: integration

When evaluating an improper integral with limits $_{-\infty}^\infty$, why do we need to separate the integral into $\int\limits_a^{\infty} \text{  and  } \int\limits_{-\infty}^a$?

My homework asked the question:

> True or False?
>
> If $f$ is continuous, then $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx = \displaystyle\lim_{t \to \infty} \int\limits_{-t}^t f(x)dx$

I thought that the RHS would come out to be the same answer, but the textbook says false.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80262/why-is-int-infty-infty-fracxx21-dx-not-zero).

Comment: By definition $\int \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f$ equals $\int \limits_{-\infty}^{0}f+\int \limits_{0}^{+\infty}f$, if both of these last two integrals converge. Otherwise it's undefined.